# verifying certificates

Tags: certificates, openssl

In my test setup I have a root CA only.  I also have a node cert (`joe0.lab.local.pem`).  I did the following:

```
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem joe0.lab.local.pem 
joe0.lab.local.pem: CN = joe0.lab.local
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

**The node cert was NOT signed by ca.pem**.  Is this the expected output when you have an incorrect certificate chain?

Just looking for a sanity check.

Comment: If the specific cert (not really a chain) isn't a direct child of a (specified or defaulted) CA, yes this is the expected result. If you have 'only [one] root CA' why is your cert not signed by it?

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085.  This is purely an academic exercise.